# Gravity equation: Is it always appropriate to use ppml?

Tags: panel-data, econometrics, stata, dyadic-data

I am interested in estimating countries' comparative advantage. Following
[Costinot et al.](https://economics.mit.edu/files/7796) (2012) which is a
many-sector version of [Eaton and Kortum](http://www.princeton.edu/~erossi/courses_files/EKn.pdf) I have the following theoretical relationship
between trade flows and productivities.
$$
\left(  \frac{X_{ij}^{k}X_{i^{\prime}j}^{k^{\prime}}}{X_{ij}^{k^{\prime}%
}X_{i^{\prime}j}^{k}}\right)  =\left(  \frac{A_{i}^{k}}{A_{i}^{k^{\prime}}%
}\frac{A_{i^{\prime}}^{k^{\prime}}}{A_{i^{\prime}}^{k}}\right)  ^{\theta
}\left(  \frac{d_{ij}^{k}}{d_{ij}^{k^{\prime}}}\frac{d_{i^{\prime}%
j}^{k^{\prime}}}{d_{i^{\prime}j}^{k}}\right)  ^{-\theta}%
$$
where

- $X_{ij}^{k}$ are sector $k$ trade flows from country $i$ to country $j$
- $A_{i}^{k}$ is country $i$'s (labor) productivity in sector $k$
- $d_{ij}^{k}$ are the corresponding trade costs
- $\theta$ is an elasticity whose value I take from the literature.

The double-ratio $\left(  A_{i}^{k}A_{i^{\prime}}^{k^{\prime}}\right)
/\left(  A_{i^{\prime}}^{k}A_{i}^{k^{\prime}}\right)  $ is country $i$'s
comparative advantage in sector $k$. Following Costinot et al., I derive the
estimation equation from the theoretical relationship above in two steps.
First, I take logs and control for the differences by adding appropriate
fixed effects:

$$
\log\left(  X_{ij}^{k}\right)  =\theta\log\left(  A_{i}^{k}\right)
+\delta_{j}^{k}+\delta_{ij}-\theta\log\left(  d_{ij}^{k}\right)  ,
$$
where $\delta_{j}^{k}$ is an importer-sector fixed effects that controls for
exporter-difference and $\delta_{ij}$ is an exporter-importer fixed effect
that controls for differences over sectors. In the second step I replace
$\theta\log\left(  A_{i}^{k}\right)  $ by an exporter-sector fixed effect
$\left(  \delta_{i}^{k}\right)  $ and I view the trade costs $\left(
d_{ij}^{k}\right)  $ as the error term $\left(  \varepsilon_{ij}^{k}\right)  $
so that the estimation equation becomes
$$
\log\left(  X_{ij}^{k}\right)  =\delta_{i}^{k}+\delta_{j}^{k}+\delta
_{ij}+\varepsilon_{ij}^{k}.\label{estimation equation}%
$$
Costinot et al. estimate this using OLS.

**Please correct me if I am wrong** (and keep in mind that econometrics is not one
of my strong points). Assuming that $\varepsilon_{ij}^{k}$ is orthogonal to
the three fixed effects ($\delta_{i}^{k}$, $\delta_{j}^{k}$, $\delta_{ij}$),
the problems pointed out by [Santos-Silva and Tenreyro](http://personal.lse.ac.uk/tenreyro/jensen08k.pdf) (SST) do not apply here. Using the notation from above, SST discuss the case where the estimation equation
is of the form
$$
X_{ij}^{k}=\exp\left(  \delta_{i}^{k}+\delta_{j}^{k}+\delta_{ij}\right)
+\varepsilon_{ij}^{k}\label{estimation equation ppml}%
$$
whereas my estimation equation above implies that
$$
X_{ij}^{k}=\exp\left(  \delta_{i}^{k}+\delta_{j}^{k}+\delta_{ij}%
+\varepsilon_{ij}^{k}\right)  .\label{estimation equation 2}%
$$
In this case, it seems to me, estimation by OLS is fine.

Related question: Given that I have many zeros in the data set, would it then be **wrong** to estimate my estimation equation with ppml? My own answer to this question is that I lose the tight connection between the theoretical model and my estimates. My variable of interest $δ_{i}^{k}$ does not have the same interpretation in both cases. Again, please correct me if I am wrong.